# Supertest + express setup cause timeout error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I have a simple setup on the server.test.js

```js
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

const request = require('supertest');
const express = require("express")
const app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'john' });
});

describe('GET /user', function() {
  it('responds with json', async function(done) {
    const response = await request(app)
      .get('/user')
    expect(response.status).toBe(201)
  })
})
```

`npx jest` and receive `thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.,` increasing timeout doesn't help in jest.config.js to testTimeout: 20000, it waits for the 20s and also fails

**Why express app start with superset? I used an example from the official README**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `done` from the test callback:

```
it('responds with json', async function() {
  const response = await request(app)
    .get('/user')
  expect(response.status).toBe(201)
})
```

Jest may be waiting for it to be called.

Generally it's recommended that you either use an `async` function or `done`. Jest normally warns if you mix them, not sure why it doesn't do so wit this setup.

Alternatively you can try to call `done()` at the end of the test.

You should expect for the test to fail because the status that gets posted is `200` and you are checking for `201`.